# evaluation of passed parameters in macros

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, c++14

```
#define prod(a) (a*a)
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int i = 3, j, k, l;
  j = prod(i++);
  cout << i << endl;
  k = prod(++i);
  cout << i << endl;
  l = prod(i+1);

  cout << i << " " << j << " " << k << " " << l;
}
```

Why is variable "`i`" incremented twice?

i.e to 5 from 3 after `j=prod(i++);`

Comment: I recommend you take some time to read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: And the take-home advice: Stop using macros! 
With C++14 you can write something like the following and get the result you want:

template <typename A, typename B> auto prod(const A& a, const B& b) { return a*b; }

Answer (score 2):

Remember that macros are *expanded* in the source code, not actually called or evaluated.

That means a "call" like

```
prod(i++)
```

results in the expanded code

```
i++*i++
```

being seen by the compiler.

Many compilers allow you to stop after preprocessing, or otherwise generate preprocessed source, that you can examine to see macro expansions.

---

If you continue using such a macro with other expressions as arguments, you will soon see another reason they are bad.

Lets say you use

```
prod(2+4)
```

Then that will result in the expansion

```
2+4*2+4
```

which is equal to

```
2+(4*2)+4
```

which is equal to 14, not 36 which might have been expected.

Comment: They don't need to go further: `i++ * i++` is already undefined behavior. Two assignments to `i` without a sequence point in between.

Comment: @BillLynch It's not really *assignment* to `i`, and with the new sequenced-before and -after rules of C++11 and later, I'm not so sure about the UB any more. If I read [this evaluation order reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) (especially [rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Rules) 1, 2, and 4) correctly I don't think it's UB.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's undefined because there is no sequenced-before relationship between the two operands of the `*` operator, and each one of them modifies `i`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is variable "i" incremented twice? i.e to 5 from 3 after j=prod(i++)

Because `prod()` is a macro, not a function, so

```
k=prod(++i);
```

become

```
k=(++i * ++i);
```